# Get productType for creating a listing on amazon with SP API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

Hello I am developing an integration with Amazon SS API to automate listing products for a specific client.

I have gotten to the point where I am able to generate access tokens.

I can fetch existing listings using [get-listings2021-08-01itemsselleridsku endpoint](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-reference#get-listings2021-08-01itemsselleridsku).

I am now trying to create listings using use the [put-listings2021-08-01itemsselleridsku endpoint](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-reference#put-listings2021-08-01itemsselleridsku).

I am following [this tutorial](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-use-case-guide#step-1-submit-listings-item-put-request), but when it describes the JSON object to submit the actual product details to make the listing everything goes super meta.

Apparently you are supposed to use a different api to fetch your product type and then look up the required fields for that specific product type in the schema to know how to represent them.

I have been able to use the product type search endpoint to search for product types, specifically [get-definitions2020-09-01producttypes](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-type-definitions-api-v2020-09-01-reference#get-definitions2020-09-01producttypes) to do searches, but the options which come back are not useful.  You can search by keyword or by product name.  My client sells vinyl records.  So I have searched for music, record, lp, vinyl about anything I can think of and I do not find a valid product type which is returned by that endpoint.

I have searched for this problem and have found an [old github issue](https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api/issues/217) identifying the same issue, but following the links it circles back to what I already have found.

I am using Postman to make the requests and have imported the relevant models.

- How do I find a valid productType for Vinyl Records?
- Do different productType's have to be enabled somehow for why the get-definitions endpoint doesn't return useful results?
- Is there a different endpoint for creating listings which is recommended which is better supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem with books... I was surprised that books doesn't have their own product type. Actually all media including records, do not have their own product type!

I did figure out that a productType of "PRODUCT" will work fro Books and I suspect it will work for records as well.

Here's a sample body for the PUT listing  to help explain what worked for me:

**PUT [https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/{your-seller-id}/{your-custom-sku}?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER](https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/%7Byour-seller-id%7D/%7Byour-custom-sku%7D?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER)**

```
{
      "productType": "PRODUCT",
      "requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
      "attributes": {
        "purchasable_offer": [
          {
            "currency": "USD",
            "our_price": [
              {
                "schedule": [
                  {
                    "value_with_tax": 44.33
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ],
        "condition_note": [
          {
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "value": "Book in good condition. Cover is in good condition. Binding is good. Ships direct from Amazon!",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ],
        "batteries_required": [
          {
            "value": "false",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ],
        "merchant_suggested_asin": [
          {
            "value": "1718502443",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ],`enter code here`
        "condition_type": [
          {
            "value": "used_very_good",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ],
        "supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation": [
          {
            "value": "unknown",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          },
          {
            "value": "unknown",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          },
          {
            "value": "unknown",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          },
          {
            "value": "unknown",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          },
          {
            "value": "unknown",
            "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          }
        ]
      },
      "offers": [
        {
          "marketplaceId": "1718502443",
          "offerType": "B2C",
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "amount": 44.33
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

A few things to note:

- requirements == LISTING_OFFER_ONLY  (PRODUCT wont work with 'LISTING')
- Everything in the body is required values.
- For some reason the price is being set to 0.00 even though I am setting it in multiple places. I haven't figured that one out yet but I'll update when I do)
- Last, I am using a known ASIN here so I am not creating a new product. If you are trying to create something not in the catalog then more complications will likely arise!

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you, that was the trick.  I was able to post.  Now I need to figure out how to specify inventory levels.  My client is not using Amazon's fulfillment services, so I am not sure that the fulfillment_availability applies, but if it doesn't I am not sure what to use.

Comment: Also for me a price was able to get through.

Comment: Glad it helped get you going!  I was able to get the price to go through as well... it was strangely slow to show up in seller central but did eventually get there.  I'm doing FBA only at the moment so haven't dug too deep into the MF side.